# List bullet does not work for the second item

Tags: lists

I tried using a `list` in LaTeX (`pdflatex`, specifically) and I found that the second item does not have a bullet point rendered while the first and third (and remaining ones) does.  Why is it?  Please compile the code below to see what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{list}{$\bullet$}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

The `list` environment actually takes two mandatory arguments; not just one. The first is the label, while the second are any commands that require execution before entering the actual list. To obtain the correct output, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
\begin{list}{\textbullet}{}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

or just use the `itemize` environment. In fact, both `enumerate` and `itemize` use `list` to set up the appropriate list format.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the `itemize` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```